# Why am I running into a Time Limit Exceeded Error on CodeChef when the Time clocked is 0 seconds when I submit my code?

Tags: python, time-limiting

This question relates to my code running into `Time Limit Exceeded Error` on Codechef- although the **time clocked is 0 seconds**?

Here is the problem I am trying to solve:
https://www.codechef.com/SEPT21C/problems/MNDIGSUM

[image]

And here is my code:

```
Q = int(input())
res = float("inf")
curr = float("inf")
answer = float("inf")

#converts any positive integer 'temp' with base 10 into its equivalent in base 'base'
def numberToBase(n, b,stopper):
    counter = 0
    if n == 0:
        return [0]
    digits = []
    while n:
        digits.append(int(n % b))
        counter += int(n % b)
        n //= b
        if counter>stopper:
            break
    return sum(digits[::-1])

for i in range(Q):
    answer = float("inf")
    res = float("inf")
    curr = float("inf")
    count = float("inf")
    (n,l,r) = list(map(int,input().split()))
    for j in range(l,r+1):
        count = min(count,curr)
        curr = numberToBase(n,j,curr)
        if curr<res:
            answer = j
        res = min(res,curr)
    print(answer)
```

Am I missing something- because when I run my code in PyCharm, and **run the basic three tests** on the website, it produces the same output as expected!

I looked on a number of forums and there was a mention of the CodeChef compiler reading my **inputs too slowly**? But I've never had this problem when answering previous problems in the same manner, I mean in terms of setting up the input.

Comment: Coding competition sites often use extreme inputs to make sure the algorithm performance is optimal.

Comment: Please post the description of the problem here. Your link requires a login.

Comment: I think your while loop is the problem... https://www.purplemath.com/modules/logrules5.htm

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer, you're completely right- let me amend it and run it again

Comment: For future reference, how did you paste the screenshot on the question?